# Looping trough pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, iterator

I have 2 Dataframes,

- one from my back end (df_be) with timestamp, id and id_type (id_type identifies what is the type of the ID on ID field, which can be a box/device/account. If it is box/device it is shown a mac address if it is account it's shown an account number.
- one from another dataframe (df_sa) that contains two columns (sa, mac_stb) with all the correspondence between all mac addresses and all client accounts that exists.

What i need to do is, for every client account found in df_be (this ones doesn't have mac addresses at the beggining), i need to search for a correspondence in df_sa and add a column on df_be with all correspondent mac addresses. The code below already does the job, but is very very very unefficient. I was looking for a solution for this, since this is not suitable for the amount of information that i have.

Thank you very much in advance!

```
# Iterate through df_be with mac_stb = NaN
for i in np.arange(sum(df_be['mac_stb'].isnull())):
    # Get account number when mac_stb = NaN
    account = df_be[df_be['mac_stb'].isnull()].iloc[i]['id']

    # Copy row with mac_stb = NaN so that you can replace it later by the appropriates mac_stb
    new_df_be_row = df_be[df_be['mac_stb'].isnull()][df_be['id'] == account].copy()

    # Iterate through mac_stb associated with account id
    for mac in df_sa.loc[df_sa['sa'] == account]['mac_stb']:
        new_df_be_row['mac_stb'] = mac
        df_be = df_be.append(new_df_be_row, ignore_index=True)

# Drop rows with mac_stb = NaN as these have been replaced with possible mac_stb
df_be.dropna(subset=['mac_stb'], inplace=True)
df_be.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Raw data:

```
    timestamp               time_ms id              id_type mac_stb
720 2019-07-07 17:16:06.304 18.0    641269DD04B1    boxId   641269DD04B1
721 2019-07-07 17:16:06.291 9.0     98F7D7198F88    boxId   98F7D7198F88
722 2019-07-07 17:16:06.291 6.0     A0C5624B2D79    boxId   A0C5624B2D79
723 2019-07-07 17:16:06.288 18.0    7085C6AAB849    device  7085C6AAB849
724 2019-07-07 17:16:06.304 18.0    S828093664      account NaN
725 2019-07-07 17:16:06.319 4.0     707630BC92E7    boxId   707630BC92E7
726 2019-07-07 17:16:06.319 8.0     S827336056      account NaN
727 2019-07-07 17:16:06.320 9.0     707630BC8FA8    device  707630BC8FA8
728 2019-07-07 17:16:06.340 9.0     S831286437      account NaN
729 2019-07-07 17:16:06.335 13.0    S841512815      account NaN

    mac_stb         mac_cm          sa
0   001E690D2C83    001E690D2C82    S827336056
1   001E690D2D8F    001E690D2D8E    S831286437
2   001E690D311D    001E690D311C    S841512815
3   001E690D4053    001E690D4052    S830161775
4   001E690D4B91    001E690D4B90    S825327910
```

IGNORE mac_cm

IMPORTANT UPDATE:
For each account it is possible to existe more than one mac_stb, so for each request in BE it must have all mac_stb possible shown, if there is more than one, it should add a new row with the second/third mac_stb available.

Examples:
[This is the example of df_be before populating mac_stb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlJjh.png)

[This is the example of df_sa with mac correspondence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nc9Ks.png)

[This is the example of what should look like the rows which have client accounts after being populated with mac_stb from df_sa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHPj9.png)

Comment: thanks for the explanation & code - what would really help is your dataframes with your intended output to contextualize the problem. read [mcve]

Comment: posted some pictures of examples

Comment: can you add the raw data? paste it in inside a code blob the problem at the moment is not reproducable.

Comment: Sorry it was my first post in this kind of forums. Updated! Hope it is ok now. but the df_sa is too short for some kind of correlation in this case, i cant upload 1000000 lines xD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use merge. It may look rather complex, but in essence it is very similar to your solution. The mask replaces your first loop and the merge() replaces the second loop. The rest is just cleaning up.

```
mask_no_mac_stb = df_be['mac_stb'].isnull()
df_merged = pd.merge(df_be[mask_no_mac_stb], df_sa, left_on='id', right_on='sa').set_index('id').drop('mac_stb_x', axis=1).rename({'mac_stb_y': 'mac_stb'}, axis=1)
df_be = df_be.set_index('id')
df_be.loc[df_merged.index, 'mac_stb'] = df_merged.loc[df_merged.index, 'mac_stb']
df_be = df_be.reset_index()
```

**UPDATE:**

If you cannot guarantee that all ids are unique, you can use a dict and apply:

```
mask_no_mac_stb = df_be['mac_stb'].isnull()
map_id2mac = {id: mac for (id, mac) in zip(df_sa['sa'].to_list(), df_sa['mac_stb'].to_list())}
df_be.loc[mask_no_mac_stb, 'mac_stb'] = df_be.loc[mask_no_mac_stb, 'id'].apply(lambda x: map_id2mac.get(x, np.nan))
```

Output for provided raw data (identical for both ways):

```
             id     timestamp  time_ms  id_type       mac_stb
0  641269DD04B1  17:16:06.304    18.00    boxId  641269DD04B1
1  98F7D7198F88  17:16:06.291     9.00    boxId  98F7D7198F88
2  A0C5624B2D79  17:16:06.291     6.00    boxId  A0C5624B2D79
3  7085C6AAB849  17:16:06.288    18.00   device  7085C6AAB849
4    S828093664  17:16:06.304    18.00  account           NaN
5  707630BC92E7  17:16:06.319     4.00    boxId  707630BC92E7
6    S827336056  17:16:06.319     8.00  account  001E690D2C83
7  707630BC8FA8  17:16:06.320     9.00   device  707630BC8FA8
8    S831286437  17:16:06.340     9.00  account  001E690D2D8F
9    S841512815  17:16:06.335    13.00  account  001E690D311D
```

Note: The value for id 7085C6AAB849 is still NaN, because it is not in df_sa

Comment: I think something is wrong when populating the mac_stb on df_be for account types. I understand your code, but my ouput is still null for account types

Comment: It gives the error "Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Comment: It doesnt give an error anymore, but it doesn't populate my mac_stb field anyway. My dataframes are much much bigger than the raw data i put there. and all account number have 1 or more mac_stb associated, and i need all of them. so i need to add columns to df_ be if needed